# Excluding some pattern from pattern_match in php

Tags: php, preg-split

I am trying to split raw text into sentences. So I simply use `preg_split()` function and split a raw text into sentence based on occurrence of `?`, `.` and `;`. But as expected I faced some problem due to some special case of `.` for example "Dr.", "Mr.", etc.

How can I exclude such word, or patter from spliting?

```
preg_split('/(\. )|(\? )|(\; )!(Mr\.)/', $content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add [negative lookbehind](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to the regex to make sure that the dot is not preceded by "Mr" and company:

```
preg_split('/((?<!(Mr|Dr))\.|\?|;) /', $content);
```

I also simplified the regex a little bit. You should also consider substituting `\s|$` (any whitespace or end of input) for the single space at the end of the current expression.

**[See it in action](http://ideone.com/pjkJM)**.

Comment: Thanks @Jon .....
But do we can predict any pattern for such as special occurred pattern (Dr., Mr., Mrs. etc)